# Maven 2.1 dependency:analyze. Transitive dependencies: Used undeclared dependencies found

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I am using the `dependency:analyze` to detect dependency problems. But I have found a problem with the transitive dependencies because the plugin doesn't resolve this dependencies.

When I execute mvn dependency:tree, the output shows the transitive dependencies.

**Dependencies**

```
project A
  dependency B
project C
  dependency A
```

**Outuput -> (project C - path)/ mvn clean install**

```
[WARNING] Used undeclared dependencies found:
   dependency B: compile
```

**Plugin**

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>analyze</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>analyze-only</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
            </configuration>
       </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Why the plugin doesn't detect the transitive dependency**

Comment: Not really enough information here to answer your question. What did you expect the output to say? Which project did you run the analysis on?

Comment: I execute "mvn clean install" on Project C. If I put the failOnWarning option to false, the warning dissapears and the execution is OK. Why the plugin doesn't detect the transitive dependency

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dependency analysis works as expected.

Code in project C uses classes from project B but it does not directly depend on project B. It compiles only because it transitively depend on B through project A. Changing dependency of project A would break project C. This is what we are trying to avoid

This is not good, if the code uses classes from B, it should **directly** depend on B.

Comment: I need the Project A dependency because contains common libraries and code

Comment: That is also fine, let C depend on A and B.

Comment: No, I shouldn't do this, and I am trying to work with transitive dependencies.

Comment: Does your code in project A directly use code from project B? I mean importing classes.

Comment: Yes, In both projects, A and C, I need to import Project B classes

Comment: So in this case, project C should directly depend on project B. That is the rule that dependency analyzer follows. If you don't follow that rule then changing dependency of project A would break project C. This is what we are trying to avoid.

Comment: @Grzegorz is right. A rule of thumb is to declare in your module's pom, all dependency directly used by your module's classes. Across a project life, refactoring can lead a dependency to disappear from a module. If other modules were relying on transitive dependencies to have the disappeared dependency in the classpath, this would lead to compilation failures.

Comment: Can you edit your answer to remove "Everything is fine"? Without a direct dependency on B, everything isn't fine. ;)